# Login code in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

```
try { 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/supermarket?username=root&pa‌​ssword="); 
    Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username '" + username + "' AND password = PASSWORD( '" + password + "')");
    rs.next(); 

    if (rs.getRow() == 1) { 
        setVisible(false); 
        new Home().setVisible(true); 
    } 
    else { 
        jLabelAlarm.setText("Incorrect Username or Password!"); 
    }
} catch (Exception e) { 
}
```

I am new in java. This code belongs to login for connecting to MySQL server, but after running it not works properly.

Comment: Please copy-paste the code into the question here! Furthermore specify what does the "it not works properly" means -- does it throw an exception or anything?

Comment: Lastly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, use `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: It mean after inserting true Username and Password the login frame is available and asks for Username and Password.

Comment: Change `} catch (Exception e) { 
}` to `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); //DON'T IGNORE EXCEPTIONS!
}`

Comment: [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Please specify add information in the question about the exact problem you have: What error messages do you see (if any)? What do you expect to happen vs what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/supermarket/root, "");
```

Just change the database connection code to this type.